# Saving PDF of current screen contents wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

How to generate PDF **without using 3rd party libraries** of the current screen contents in WPF. Does Microsoft have any library of their own to create a PDF document? I am developing a professional that I intend to sale hence using 3rd party libraries won't be a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official way of manipulating PDF documents is by using PDF SDK provided by Adobe. Here is the link: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html

The SDK is licensed to the developer at a fee which is charged according to the application of the SDK.